# how to change the browser of Altova XMLSpy to Chrome / FireFox / etc?

Tags: xml, xslt, xmlspy, altova

Does anyone here uses Altova XMLSpy?

Whenever i do F10 it will take an input XML and an input XSL and give me an output in the window itself (Altova XMLSpy's own browser)

So basically how do i set the browser to use like "Chrome" or "FireFox"?

**If not possible, is there anyway to make the output save to a file instead of showing the output directly in the program?**

Answer (score 0):

XMLSpy always uses IE, but you can save the generated HTML easily: Above the document tab are two buttons called `Browser` and `Text`. `Browser` is the one you are currently in because it is opened by default. Switch to `Text`, and you will see the HTML code.